# BigQuery Extract to GS with multiple wildcard URI gives EMPTY blobs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud, distributed-computing

I am trying to extract a table from BigQuery using `google.cloud.storage.Client` method `extract_table` in Python by giving as parameter in `destination_uri` an array of multiple wildcard uris.

```
destination_uri=['gs://{}/{}/{}-*'.format(bucket_name, prefix, i) for i in range(nb_node)]
```

The expected behavior is that BigQuery will split evenly my table into multiple blobs.

The file size is 242 MB with compression

What really happens is that is makes 1 file of 242 MB and 6 empty others with 20 B if I give 7 URIS.

The other configuration parameters is : `destination_format = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON" and compression="GZIP"`

Any clue on why this is happening?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, if you want your extract to be evenly sharded, use partitions in your BQ table.

Answer (score 2):

There is no distribute "evenly" concept.

Export files can be really sporadic one could be several gigabytes, others a few megabytes.

This is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) and also from our experience:

> If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, you must export your data
>   to multiple files. When you export your data to multiple files, the
>   **size of the files will vary**.

Comment: Are you relying on a source in GCP docs or by experience ? Could you please develop your point, because I cannot imagine extracts to buckets without control over file sizes.

Comment: I added the documentation it's also documented. So essential they are saying that if your `DATA > 1GB` you are forced to export multiple files. But it doesn't tell you nothing about the size it will be exported, and experience is that is very hectic, and you get pieces in various sizes even large ones like 8-10 GBs.

Comment: I agree on the interpretation of the docs, but in other cases I get blobs with equal sizes for another table. Is there a way to determine what causes BigQuery to put all data in one blob vs evenly divided blobs of table shards ?